# How to publish tablet only Android app with vector drawables

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

I have created Android application which is targeted to tablet devices only. In AndroidManifest I have set following screen support:

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

All graphics in my are vectors so the XML files are put inside the `drawable` directory directly. Only bitmaps are the launcher icons which looks like this:

```
res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png
res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png
res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
```

In developer console I'm getting a warning that my application is not designed for tablets properly **"Use Assets Designed for Tablet Screens"**.

I have tried adding `mipmap-large-mdpi\ic_launcher.png` and `mipmap-xlarge-mdpi\ic_launcher.png` but it had no effect on the warning.

What can I do, to have my app properly designed for tablets?

Comment: Did you find out a solution for this? This seems like an oversight from Google.

Comment: No luck so far.

Comment: Have you try my answer ? Did it work!

Comment: Have you tried with add all your vactor drawables inside folder like "drawable-sw600dp" ?

Comment: Create one fake not used in project png drawable and put into drawble folders mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same app always works for phone and tablet. **Phone and tablet** is the same category. But Android TV, wearables are different categories. Google Developer console asks you to provide tablet screen images because tablet requires relatively large images. And these images are bitmaps. so you have to provide bitmap images for the tablet while you publish Apk.

Since VectorAssets look the same in every density (size) screens. But for the **bitmaps** (eg, ic_launcher.png, Action Bar & Tab Icon, Notification icons), it should be properly designed using Android Studio Asset Manager.

"**Use Assets Designed for Tablet Screens**" is explicitly stated problems. So, generate all **bitmaps** using Android Studio Asset Manager.

Eg, to generate (replace your launcher icons): right click on ic_launcher.png" package > new > Image Asset > Change the Asset type to image > and then complete ....

Below image for more clarification.[image]

**Note**: You don't require below lines in `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can delete whole `<supports-screens />` block.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: This is not necessary when using vector images, the whole point of them is so you do not need multiple images for multiple densities.

Comment: @DrBreakalot, please read the line `Since VectorAssets look the same in every density (size) screens`

Answer (score 3):

To get your app filtered for just Tablets running ICS in Google-Play you would do this in your AndroidManifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

To get HoneyComb Tablets as well you simply change your minSdk

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Comment: What is the reason for targeting 14?

Comment: There might be chances where the assets are not supported in the latest version. But the 14 version has a perfect stable firmware. It can be used to check if there is any compatibility issues

Comment: Since some apps may only support minSdkVersion='21' for example, this is not a very good solution

Comment: That's true. But need to check if it is a problem with the apk or with the play console right. So I suggested this!

Answer (score 2):

If you think it does not apply to you, the only solution is to appeal to Google. All other solutions are workarounds that are not necessary.

You can contact Google to appeal an issue with "Designed for tablets" at:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq

Answer (score 1):

```
`android:largeScreens="true"`
```

to

```
`android:largeScreens="false"`
```

as referred from **Declaring an App is Only for Tablets** in [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps) with a
 `Caution:`
 If you use the  element for the reverse scenario (when your application is not compatible with larger screens) and **set the larger screen size attributes to "false", then external services such as Google Play do not apply filtering.** Your application will still be available to larger screens, but when it runs, it will not resize to fit the screen. Instead, the system will emulate a handset screen size (about 320dp x 480dp; see Screen Compatibility Mode for more information). If you want to prevent your application from being downloaded on larger screens, use , as discussed in the previous section about Declaring an App is Only for Handsets.

best wishes to you, HOPE this work for You.